# Add an EC2 instance as a worker to Amazon MWAA

Tags: amazon-ec2, airflow, celery, mwaa

I am currently using Amazon MWAA as my Airflow. I want to have 2 types of workers nodes but currently MWAA doesn't support it. I want to have:

1. High Compute Optimized CPU workers
2. GPU workers

I want to create different queues for both the worker types and submit jobs to these workers nodes.

Is it possible to add an existing EC2 instance (say GPU instance) to MWAA? I only see Start and Stop EC2 operators available.

Does anyone have any pointers on this?

Comment: I solved it with EKS. I defined there different pool for cpu and gpu and use KubernetesPodOperator

Comment: @ozs can you give more pointers on this? So you migrated from MWAA to EKS and using KubernetesPodOperator? Any more pointers will be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: EKS is working beside the MWAA. its a docker containers orchestrator. I'll add in the answer another solution and easier.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have an EKS then its possible to define a GPU pool and using KubernetesPodOperator you can run a docker under a gpu pool.
2. Another solution its ECS (easier to define). you can see a good example to run gpu in Airflow in this [article](https://medium.com/fandom-engineering/gpu-based-workloads-as-a-part-of-airflow-dags-1d856418b529)